# SQL Select statement with double Quote string condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is my first question in this respected site.

I have a very simple SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PRODUCT_NAME='14"" Television'
```

When I run it I get this message:
**Syntax error near 'Television' in the full-text search condition '"14" Television"'.**

The actual value of this column is 14" Television. But when I use `Request.Form("Product")` it adds another " to the string so it become (14"" Television)!

How can I bypass this?
I tried to replace the double quotes with one using this method:

```
 Product = Product.Replace("""",chr(34))
```

but it didn't work!

EDIT: SOLVED LIKE THIS

```
product = product.replace(""","")

SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE CONTAINS(PRODUCTS.*,'"14 Television"')
```

Comment: Never ever do it like that. It protected you from the start against SQL injection attack. Instead use parameters.

Comment: Even in parameters same problem.

Comment: Why it adds another " to the string ?! As far as I know Request.form() suppose to return the exact string! but here it adds a " and make it 2 double quotes instead of one!

Comment: Are you forming this query in C#?

Comment: This is not a SQL Server question, it's (I think) an ASP .Net question - if you add the correct tags the right people might respond.

Comment: I solved it by replacing the double quotes with an empty string.And using CONTAINS instead of equal.

Comment: Thank you guys.

Happy to be here.

Comment: It became like this:

SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PRODUCT_NAME 
CONTAINS(PRODUCTS.*,'"14 Televison"')

Comment: It might be an ASP, ASP.Net question or C#, VB.Net or some non-MS language question. Request.Form("product") makes us suspect Asp\Asp.Net but it is not only used by ASP\ASP.Net. Whatever it is, the query string is "constructed" and sent to server, which is a NO-NO. Use parameters. You think you solved it, but I am afraid you are only opening Pandora's box. Hopefully the server doesn't keep  anything to lose.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PRODUCT_NAME=REPLACE( '14"" Television', '""','"')
```

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work no result is showing it seems like replace is not "replacing" at all!

Comment: remove the last " , it will help you , i've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to SQL Server at the moment, but if I remember correctly, your condition should look like this `'14" Television'` (I presume the text should be `14" Television`.

With that said, the only thing I see wrong with the query is the fact you opened a literal with a single quote and closed it with a double quote (literals should be enclosed in single quotes from both sides, if I remember correctly).